# How to hide/show a ContentChild in the parent

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I'm building a tabs component using Angular6, and need to show only one component depending on the active tab. How can i acomplish that?

I have this structure

```
<tabs-ui>
    <tab-pane title="Tab 1" key="1">
        <div animate="fadeInLeft">Mi contenido 1</div>
    </tab-pane>
    <tab-pane title="Tab 2" key="2">
            <div animate="fadeInLeft">Mi contenido 2</div>
    </tab-pane>
    <tab-pane title="Tab 3" key="3">
        <div animate="fadeInLeft">Mi contenido 3</div>
    </tab-pane>
</tabs-ui>
```

Where tabs-ui is the parent and has a ng-content tag

I'm grabbing the children element using this

```
@ContentChildren(TabPaneComponent) tabsPanes: QueryList<TabPaneComponent>;
```

How could i hide or show the children depending on an property inside *tabs-ui*?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use *ngIf in your template:

```
<tabs-ui>
    <tab-pane title="Tab 1" key="1" *ngIf="selectedContent === 'A'">
        <div animate="fadeInLeft">Mi contenido 1</div>
    </tab-pane>
    <tab-pane title="Tab 2" key="2" *ngIf="selectedContent === 'B'">
            <div animate="fadeInLeft">Mi contenido 2</div>
    </tab-pane>
    <tab-pane title="Tab 3" key="3" *ngIf="selectedContent === 'C'">
        <div animate="fadeInLeft">Mi contenido 3</div>
    </tab-pane>
</tabs-ui>
```

selectedContent is a property on your component. Changing it between A, B, and C will reveal the appropriate content.

Comment: Simple, but highly effective. The beauty of Angular.